Initial condition before t=0 switching

This is a problem that I'm trying to solve. I am an electronics student.
My approach to this problem was, Since it is a series RLC circuit, I tried finding initial values i(0-), v(0-) just before switching.

Since, before t=0 the steady state the left branch with 1F Capacitor and 3-ohm resistor acts like an open circuit, and the only loop in the circuit is the middle and right branch. Therefore, current towards inductor is IL(0-) = 2A, but i(0-) = 0,

The voltage across capacitor v(0-) = 0V as 2H is shorted in steady state and ground is 0.

Also finally, After switching i(t) = IL(t).


Please, help me in correcting me if I'm wrong.

All correct as far as I can see, but of course finding IL(t) is the next step in the solution.
